# breaking an integer into parts

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to add all the digits in an integer value until i get a value below 9 using Javascript.

for an example, if i have 198, I want to add these together like 1 + 9 + 8 = 18, and since 18 is higher than 9 add 1 +8 again = 9.

Comment: This seems to be need maybe just one more step than your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151224/how-to-sum-individual-digits-of-integer Do you not know that additional step or do you not know the syntax of javascript or both or others? Let us know what you do not know and what you know with regards to this question so we can help you better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than giving you full code I would just explain how to do it.

You can do modulo math by number%10 and subsequent int divide by 10 (number/10) until you get 0 to get all the digits of a number. Sum the individual digits and until sum > 9 repeat the above process in a loop.

**Edit**: okay here is the code for you:

```
<script>
var num=198;
n = num;
var sum;
do {
   sum = 0;
   while (n>0) {
      rem = (n % 10);
      sum += rem;
      n = (n - rem)/10;    
   }
   n = sum;
} while(sum>9);

alert("sum is: " + sum);

</script>
```

Comment: can u give me a sample code for this? i'm a JavaScript novice

Comment: @megazoid: Addition, modulo and division works the same as in any other language. Same for arrays (mostly), but you can have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 1):

```
function foo(var x)
{
    while(x > 9)
    {
        var y = 0;
        while(x!=0)
        {
            y += x%10;
            x = Math.floor(x/10);
        }
        x = y;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: This above code won't work because it is NOT doing integer division. Please see my answer above.

Comment: i get the answer here, but also i get decimal points as well how come?

Comment: @anubhava Are you sure that in JavaScript we can't do integer division? Maybe you are right now I'm not using JS, maybe I have forgotten something )

Comment: In Javascript we need to call either Math.ceil or Math.floor to get int division.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two hints: `(i % 10)` gives the least significant decimal digit of `i`, while `i /= 10` removes the least significant digit from `i`. The rest is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Can you migrate my C# code to Javascript?

int i = 723;
int acc;
do {
    acc = 0;
    while (i > 0)
    {
        acc += i % 10;
        i /= 10;
    }
    i = acc;
} while(acc>=10);

Comment: @megazoid: Please see my answer above for javascript code of your question.